# How can a F-2 visa holder establish a company but can't work inside the US?

Tags: criminal-law, immigration, workplace, visa, f2-visa

As I searched about, I found that establishing a new company inside the US is allowed for everyone, but working inside the US is not allowed for certain type of visas like F-2 visa that is a student's(F-1) dependent visa.

How can a F-2 visa holder have a company in the US but he/she can not work for his/her company? Does it mean he/she can work for his/her company in real but he/she can not write a wage/salary check for his/herself?

I mean the police won't come to the office and say "Wow! you are a F-2 visa holder and you don't have a right to work inside the US. You must leave your office and go home(or maybe court :) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You don’t have to work for a company you own

I’m an owner of 3 private companies and part owner of dozens of public companies. I only work for one. Other people are employed to do the work.

So, you can start a company you are not allowed to work for and that company (at your direction) can employ other people who are allowed to work.

See [Are directors employees of the company?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/66855/are-directors-employees-of-the-company/66856)

Comment: Yes, pretty sure agree with you. But hiring other people, thinking about what strategies should the company choose, leading the managers/employees, monitoring the market/ other competitors, finding and talking to investors, etc. All of these are jobs that I think a business owner should(or maybe likes) to do/participate in, directly or indirectly, and my question is: "Will the US government punish an entrepreneur with F-2 visa status who established a company in the US and loves to do these?".

Comment: @ensan3kamel worth its own question I thought